# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, generics, exception

I am passing arrays of this kind:-

```
Integer[] A={32,543,423};
Integer[] B={32,43};
```

to the method:

```
public void method1(K[] Items1, N[] Items2, integerSerializerObject){  
    method2(Items1, Items2);               // this method again passes on the parameters to method2 & method3
}
```

which passes on to:-

```
public void method2(K... things1){  
}   

public void method3(N... things2){  
}
```

**method2 & method3 actually belongs to a library called Hector for accessing Cassandra DB, so error is not there but in my own code, which is only uptil above this method. I am passing these 2 arrays along with IntegerSerializer objects for converting those array elements to bytes. The complete list exception details are as follows:** (However I feel that the bug is somewhere in my code rather in library function, thus may be visible in my code)

I am getting an exception with this message:-

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:514)  
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:121)  
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.IntegerSerializer.fromByteBuffer(IntegerSerializer.java:42)  
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.IntegerSerializer.fromByteBuffer(IntegerSerializer. java:12)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.AbstractSerializer.fromBytesMap(AbstractSerializer.java:115)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftMultigetSliceQuery$1.doInKeyspace(ThriftMultigetSliceQuery.java:67)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftMultigetSliceQuery$1.doInKeyspace(ThriftMultigetSliceQuery.java:59)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.KeyspaceOperationCallback.doInKeyspaceAndMeasure(KeyspaceOperationCallback.java:20)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecute(ExecutingKeyspace.java:65)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftMultigetSliceQuery.execute(ThriftMultigetSliceQuery.java:58)
```

Do you guys have any idea where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you should post more code if you want us to guess where the exception lies.

Comment: show the part of the code where you are iterating in the array/s. It's likely you're **going beyond the size of the array**

Comment: Full code is required. Please post it.

Comment: I am not iterating over the array, I have passed the Integer arrays to a library method along with passing the Serializer Object (for Integer type) that will convert it to bytes which will then be stored in DB. Perhaps the method from library that serializes this array elements, is throwing the excception.

Comment: Varargs and generics don't leave happy together. See this video (starting from 19:03), one of the puzzles described there illustrates this in depth http://vimeo.com/17159900

Comment: Your question is woefully incomplete and you are not going to get a good answer until you post more of the code.  The error is in `IntegerSerializer` and nowhere in the stack trace (at least what you have posted) are method1 and method2 mentioned.  POST ALL THE CODE PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i knew, Varargs can only be used for the last parameter. As this site states:

> Varargs can be used only in the final
>   argument position.

(http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

May that produce your exception?